# File I/O while file is open (HTML5 Ogg live streaming)

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, ogg

I have just a quick question: Are files created before they are finished, or are they finished and then created?

For example, I am attempting to create a web-based Spotify using JSpotify. I already have created an interface for it that runs off a server. When play is pressed it will play it on the server (which is great, if I wanted to create a Spotify remote) -- but I want to stream that to the user.

As near as I can tell, JSpotify plays/converts Spotify's stream to ogg format before playing. Now lets say instead I re-route that newly converted stream to an ogg file (say stream.ogg), can I embed the html5 audio tag and point it to stream.ogg and let the user play while the stream.ogg file is still being written to, or is stream.ogg only created after java is completely done writing to it (when close() is called)?

To take it one step further, does html5 audio need a completed file to stream from? I guess this question has more to do with the ogg format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files are created when opened for output or I/O on all systems I have ever used (and that's a lot), with the exception of RT-11, where they didn't exist until closed. But that's a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a stream, you can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html to redirect the streamcontent to your client and the file at the same time.